# How to use SQL NOT IN() to fetch exclusive list of records from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a list of all users who have received a message (at least) from a session user while excluding those who did not.

But my code excludes only one despite there being more in this category.

Here is my code:

```
$SQL="select *from message where senderID="$sender"; $result=mysqli_query($link,$SQL);$totalRows=mysqli_num_rows($result);if($totalRows<>0){for($i=0;$i<$totalRows;  $I){$resultData[$i]=mysqli_fetch _array($result);
    }for($i=0;$i<$totalRows;  $I){$receiverID=$resultData[$i]['receiver_id'];
    $select="select *from users where memberID NOT IN($receiverID)";}  }
```

Please, how do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Please verify your code. I attempted to format it to make it readable. But, it appears you missed a closing }.

Comment: Based on the appearance of "mysqli_query", I removed the vb.net tag and added the php tag. Please note that to make code appear as code on this site, you can start a line with four spaces - it might be helpful if you edited your question to improve the appearance of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that in one SQL query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE memberID NOT IN (SELECT receiver_id FROM message WHERE senderID = '$sender')";
```

I have no knowledge of PHP, but you will have to consult its documentation for the correct use of `for` loops to retrieve the data.